# Datatable component not aligned properly

Tags: datatables, thymeleaf

I'm using a simple table  in conjunction with [datatable.js](https://datatables.net).

If I have 6 or 7 columns no problem. The search and paginator align correctly, but with 3 or 4 columns  it shows in three columns.

In https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html
show how to properly configure this, but I'm using thymeleaf and complains about the syntax

**UPDATE 1**

I have posted my question in:
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/45926/dom-in-thymeleaf-html-pages

and this is that post:

Trying to add the code in: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html

in a thymeleaf html page, but it complains about this code:

```
"dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
```

I tried to change " by ' and use escape characters but no way.

This script in my html page, doesnt work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mensuales").DataTable({
        "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
        "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json"
        },
        "lenghtMenu": [
            [5, 12, 15, 20, -1],
            [5, 12, 15, 20, "Todos"]
        ],
        "ordering": true,
        stateSave: true
    });
});
```

Allan says the code is correct, but I not be able to use in my pages.

**UPDATE 2**

[image]
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You have a typo: `lenghtMenu`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#mensuales").DataTable({
        "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
        "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json"
        },
        "lenghtMenu": [
            [5, 12, 15, 20, -1],
            [5, 12, 15, 20, "Todos"]
        ],
        "ordering": true,
        stateSave: true
      });
    });
  /*]]>*/
</script>
```